# mysqli_connect problem

Tags: php, mysqli

This is my login script;

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username']; //kullanici adi
$password = $_POST['password']; //parola
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
    ob_start();
    include('ayar.php');
    // güvenlik amaçli sql injection önlemek için sinirlama koy
    $dbC = mysqli_connect($vthost, $vtkullanici, $vtsifre, $vtadi)
    or die('Veritabanina baglanilamadi');
    $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA('$mypassword')";//SHA çöz
    $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
    // kayit kontrol et
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // kayit eslemesi kontrol et
    if($count==1){
        // esmeleme varsa oturum aç ve yönlendir 
        session_register("admin");
        session_register("password");
        $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
        header("location:raporla.php");
    }
    else {
        $msg = "Yanlis kullanici adi yada parola";
        header("location:index.php?msg=$msg");
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
else {
    header("location:index.php?msg=Kullanici adi yada parola girmediniz");
}
?>
```

in `ayar.php` I have host, username etc. There is no problem up there. But the problem is that it's working great on local and any other host but not on this one. Here is the what server error log says.

```
[11-Jun-2011 02:01:26] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  mysqli_connect() in /home/bankalar/public_html/rapor/giris.php on line 9
```

`mysqli_connect()`. I've searched for this module on my php conf. But there's no such one. Any idea?

Comment: Is the server running PHP5 or above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **php.ini**  (this under Windows) you should have the lines:

```
...
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
...
```

be sure to have the mysqli commented out (remove the `;` before)

**Edit:** as pointed out by @datasage if you're running a Linux distro lines will have a different naming, like:

```
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
```

If you are on a shared hosting and can't access the php.ini, I suggest you drop them a line and ask to have it enabled.

If you have a private server, and don't have mysqli extension installed, follow the php manual instruction [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) for a guide on how to install it.

Otherwise, you might want to use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) class (which is in the dafault installation since php 5.1), which has big advantages even over mysqli and it's really useful to make safer your database.

Comment: That applies to windows. In linux its .so. But you do have to have the files installed for PHP to find them. Depending on your system, they may not be.

Comment: I would add one more note, you may be able to install support through a package manager on linux like "yum install php-mysql" (For RHEL based distros)

Comment: in php manuel it says;
With versions of PHP 5.3.0 and newer, mysqli uses MySQL Native Driver by default. This gives a number of benefits over libmysql.

installing php 5.3.x may fix without editing php.ini?

Comment: @Recep what's your current version, and environment? If you can, though, I suggest trying to uncomment those lines (restart your server after the changes), it's easier.

Comment: @damien 5.2.17, re-seller server.I have access to WHM console.I'm very new to that

Comment: @Recep OK, look at http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/PhpIni for how to access and edit your php.ini

Answer (score 3):

Mysqli extension is not installed or its not enabled.

How to go about fixing that depends on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the MySQLi-class, you should use it Objective Oriented:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Check out the [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php). The call you're using is just an alias for the `__construct()`-method. See if the the OO-way works for you.

Also, don't trust the user's input. Use a [PreparedStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for your Query.

Comment: If mysqli is not enabled, the object wont be available as well.

Comment: It should be activated by default (doesn't mean that it can't be deactivated)... I think the interesting question is if PHP5 is running since the MySQLi-class was introduced in PHP 5.0